# Using char for small integer (C++)

Tags: c++, integer, char

I read that one can use "char" for small integers. However, when I try,

```
unsigned char A = 4;
std::cout << A << std::endl;
```

it gives a character, not 4.

Comment: where did you read that ?
anyways, it should be unsigned chat A = '4';
and it will be stored as a character not integer

Comment: Char is implicitly used as characters, to prevent this cast to int: `std::cout << (int)A << std::endl;`

Comment: @krammer: it depends on what he wants and you mean char not chat, right?

Comment: @bames53 `signed char` often has the same representation as `char` they're still distinct types.

Comment: @krammer: No, the whole point is that the OP *wants* to store an integer value in a `char`, which is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Keith Thompson right, but I was rather of the opinion that it doesn't makes sense to do so. So the first response was to get a character. Anyhow, typecasting was not in my mind at that time

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What you are experiencing are the effects of operator overloading. The `<<` operator **assumes** that you most likely want to print a character when you hand it a variable of type `char`, therefore it behaves differently than you would expect it for integral variables.

As suggested by [Vivek Goel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9055329/430766) you can force the compiler to select the overload you actually want:

```
unsigned char a = 4;
std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(a) << std::endl;
// or
std::cout << unsigned{a} << std::endl;
```

---

Addendum: Unless you are working on an environment with severely constrained resources (esp. tiny memory), you are optimising on the wrong end. Operations on `unsigned int` are typically faster than on `unsigned char`, because your processor cannot fetch single bytes but has to get at least a multiple of 4 and mask out the other 3 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

There is an overload of `operator<<` for `std::ostream` and (`signed`/`unsigned`) `char` that performs character output; in order to output the integer value of the character, you need to perform a cast:

```
std::cout << (int)A << std::endl;
```

However, this is what’s called an “old-style” (more specifically C-style) cast. C++ has casting operators that are more explicit, easier to search for, and generally preferred:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(A) << std::endl;
```

But this is cumbersome to type; the idiomatic alternative is to use the `+` operator, which promotes its argument to (`unsigned`) `int`:

```
std::cout << +A << std::endl;
```

This is what you should use.

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
 unsigned char A = 4;
    std::cout << (int)A << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

A char **IS** a small integer (with range -127 to +127), and it is subjected to the same integer arithmetic as integers are.

The problem, here, is the concept mix-up between the internal representation (binary number representing the -127 to +127 range) with the external one, that conventionally makes the input and output functions to represent it as "the glyph whose ASCII code is the number carried on by it", while for integer, the external representation is "the character sequence that read like the integer represented in decimal form"

The simplest way to print it as a number, is convert it to `int` just before give it to the output function (like `cout << int(ch)` or whatever equivalent conversion form)

Answer (score 1):

For single objects, the increase in code size is likely to swamp the decrease in storage size, of any (the memory following the object may be needed for alignment padding). Use `int` unless you need a large array of small integers.